# How to handle multiple formats for data in the same function in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I have a function that takes 2 pairs of latitude and longitude and returns a distance in m.

```
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
      var p = Math.PI/180;
      var c = Math.cos;
      var a = 0.5 - c((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 +
           c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) *
           (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p))/2;

       return 12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a)) * 1000; // 2 * R; R = 6371 km
    }//Distance
```

(note I didn't create this function but got it from another question on SO)

I have multiple sources for latitude and longitudes and I would like to know how to handle them. I tried using `||` like this

```
var distanceFromTarget = distance(
      target.latitude || target.lat || target.lat(),
      target.longitude || target.lng || target.lng(),
      current.latitude || current.lat || current.lat(),
      current.longitude || current.lat || current.lng()
    );
```

I would like to use the function to handle input from three different formats

```
navigator.geolocation.x
```

which returns data in the format

```
{latitude: 0000, longitude:0000}
```

a plugin which returns

```
{lat: 000, lng: 000}
```

and google maps api which returns a complex object for location containing getters for lat and lng something like this:

```
location = {lat(){return latitude}, lng(){return longitude}}
```

How can I handle all three? I thought what I have above was working but now I it is clear that it is not. Distance is returning NaN when the location is in the format `target.lat()`. Also it would be nice if someone could explain how `||` works in general since I thought it would just use the next object in line if the previous one was undefined.

Comment: `||` is a short circuit operator, which means if the first case is true, the rest won't be evaluated in this case.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine. There's a small error though in the fourth argument: `current.lat` instead of `current.lng`

Comment: Thanks Chris for spotting that. Though it didn't seem to be the solution I was getitng NaN as my distance when I used data from the google maps result. I switching the order of the operators ie putting `target.lat()` before `target.lat` seems to have solved the problem. I think it was reading target.lat as  defined and then performing the operations on the function rather than the value returned by the function. I haven't tested it with the plugin case yet though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was really with how the code handled errors, like if the original current or target object was undefined. Also in the case where the position object contains a getter for `lat` and `lng` `lat()`or lng(). Then target.lat would be defined therefore I used

```
function atPosition(current, target){
    if (typeof current === "undefined" || typeof target == "undefined") {
      console.log("current or target position undefined.")
      return
    }
    //if target is function and defined set property to return value of function.
    if (typeof target === "object" && typeof target.lat === "function") {
      target.lat = target.lat();
      target.lng = target.lng();
    }

    //console.log(target);
    //if currentPosition is within 25m of target return true
    var distanceFromTarget = distance(
      target.latitude || target.lat,
      target.longitude || target.lng,
      current.latitude || current.lat,
      current.longitude || current.lng
    );
    console.log("Distance from target", distanceFromTarget);
    if (distanceFromTarget <= 25) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
```